# VBA Excel - insert copied rows in For loop

Tags: excel, for-loop, foreach, vba

I am doing a For Each loop through a set of rows. And I am copying those rows a different set of times. For instance, row 2 will be copied 3 times but row 3 is not gonna be copied and row 4 is gonna be copied 2 times.

This number of copied rows is set by a field in the excel - totalDS

The problem is, when I insert this code

```
Set RowRange = sh.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

For Each rowiter In RowRange

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To totalDS

        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Rows(rowiter.Row).Copy
            .Rows(rowiter.Row).Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

    Next i

Next rowiter
```

I will have a row right next to the one I copied and that is correct. But i need that my next step of the For loop goes to the next uncopied row. As it is right now, the For loop will just go for the next line so it will keep copying the same line over and over.

Any tips on this?

Comment: As I can tell so far, this won't work with a for/each loop. What is the aim of your approach? Do you want every line in the Range being duplicated x times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this example test sub to show how it could work. This sub goes from row `i=2` to row `LastRow=10` and duplicates every row `totalDS=2` times.

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = 10

    Dim totalDS As Long
    totalDS = 2


    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    i = 2 'we start at row i
    Do While i <= LastRow 'and we end at LastRow

        For j = 1 To totalDS 'insert row totalDs times
            sh.Rows(i).Copy 'copy row
            sh.Rows(i).Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Next j

        i = i + totalDS + 1 
           'We need to go totalDs rows forward (because we inserted
           'totalDS rows) + 1 row further to get the next new row.

        LastRow = LastRow + totalDS
           'We also need to increase LastRow by totalDS because we
           'inserted totalDS rows and LastRow also moved totalDS rows down.
    Loop

    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'it's enough to use this at the very last end
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a row, try incrementing your index by 1.  For example i = i + 1